# Cannot create a new Angular project gyp err

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I want to create an angular app and I do so as I write in the comand prompt `ng new myApp`. After launching, the console starts returning the following. I have also created a project a month ago or so, but the console didn't return anything like this:

[image]

And then it returns the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why is it so? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question about your (Angular) setup?

Comment: @Roy I don't know if this answers you question, but I use NodeJs and I write the line `ng new myApp` in the cmd of the folder where I wont my project to be (e.g C:\Users\User\Projects\Angular\myApp ng new myApp) and then the console started returning the lines and errors you see. As I said, I have already created another project a month ago, but the only thing that the console showed was `CREATE myApp/angular.json (3759 bytes)
CREATE myApp/package.json (1313 bytes)
CREATE myApp/README.md (1022 bytes)
CREATE myApp/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE myApp/tslint.json (2837 bytes)` and so on

Comment: @Roy node version - v12.18.0, npm version - 6.14.5, angular version - 7.0.2

Comment: run this `npm cache clean --force` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deinstalling and installing NodeJs again and adding to the build phase a command line task forcing to install a specific version of node:
`npm install -g node@8.12.0`

And as I wrote `ng new myApp` in the cmd, I don't have any of the errors mentioned above.

Comment: i recommended, You can use `node version manager (NVM)` for installing specific version of node.js